# Display data in dataview webpart horizontally

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

I need to display images in a list horizontally one after other.
How can this be done in a dataview webpart in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know of to do this is to put each image in a div and then use css to float those divs left.  SharePoint already has a float:left class you can tie into: "image-area-left".  So your item style in xsl would look like this:

```
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowview">
  <div class="image-area-left">
    <img class="image" src="{@FileRef}" alt="{@Title}"></img>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Note: in order to have the divs work, you'll have to probably remove the table that wraps typical DVWPs in 2010.  I don't have a working 2010 environment to test on, but if you paste your XSL in here I can certainly help.